# How do you get the Hot Towel template to work with IE 8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, backwards-compatibility, hottowel

I have built a prototype using the hot towel template which works find in most browsers but displays nothing when viewed in IE8 document mode (Using the IE 9 Developer tools). The same thing happens if for the code camper sample app.

My assumption is that its a HTML 5 issue so I have tried the following.

1. Added the html5shiv and es5-shim nuget packages.
2. Create a new bundle for the scripts in Bundle config.cs ie

   new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/compat")
               .Include("~/scripts/es5-shim.js")
               .Include("~/scripts/html5shiv.js")
     );
3. Add the new bundle to the index.cshtml view

   @using System.Web
   @using System.Web.Optimization



       Hot Towel SPA

   ```
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
   <script type="text/javascript">
       if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
           var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
           var mq = "@@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}";
           msViewportStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mq));
           document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
       }
   </script>
   @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/compat")
   ```

But the problem remains. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue or am I missing something else.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the es5 Shim and Sham libraries to the vendor bundle before he Breeze entry.

```
bundles.Add(
          new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/vendor")
            .Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/knockout-{version}.debug.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/sammy-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/toastr.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/Q.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/es5-shim.min.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/es5-sham.min.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/breeze.debug.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/bootstrap.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/moment.js")
          );
```